# How to get all specific elements that apears after an specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all specific elements that appears in DOM after a specific element by jQuery.
for example all p elements that appears after p element with id="pr3".`

```html
<div>
  <p id='pr3'></p>
  <span></span>
  <p></p> //this p element
</div>
<div>
  <p></p> //this p element
  <table>...</table>
</div>
<p></p> //this p elemnt and ...
```

for example change color of all p elements that located after id='pr3'

Comment: What do you mean by "after"?  Can you include an example output?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with your attempt and expected output

Comment: My question is not clear! @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @Hamm - Oops, picked the wrong prebaked comment I meant:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.index()`  to get the benchmark element.  resource: https://api.jquery.com/index/

```
var current_p = $( "#pr3" );
var current_p_index=$( "p" ).index( current_p )
console.log( current_p_index );
```

Use the `.slice()` method constructs to get all p elements that appears after id='pr3'. resource: https://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$( "p" ).slice( current_p_index ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: Thanks . I have an other question. is there any way to get appended p elements too? @Qwerty

Comment: Am not really clear about the Question. Pls rephrase @Hamm.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that will do this, but jQuery (and the DOM) give you all the tools you need to do it. I got to wondering how hard it would be, and it turns out not to be that bad, see comments:

```js
// Add elements following the given set of elements
// that match the given selector to the target
function addFollowing(target, set, selector) {
    target = target.add(set.nextAll(selector));
    target = target.add(set.nextAll().find(selector));
    return target;
}

// Start with #pr3
let set = $("#pr3");
let paras = $();
// Add the ones that follow it at that level
paras = addFollowing(paras, set, "p");
// Loop up through parents
set = set.parent();
while (set[0] && set[0] !== document.documentElement) {
    // Add the ones that follow at this level
    paras = addFollowing(paras, set, "p");
    set = set.parent();
}

console.log(`Found ${paras.length} p elements`);
paras.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<p>no</p>
<div>
    <p>no</p>
    <div>
        <p>no</p>
    </div>
    <div>
         <p>no</p>
         <p id="pr3">pr3</p>
         <span></span>
         <p>yes 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p>yes 2</p>
    <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <p>yes 3</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<p>yes 4</p>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>yes 5</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```